# Why does java fails trying to cast List<List<String>> to Collection<Collection<String>>

Tags: java, list, collections

So i'm having this error in one of my projects, where I have a method which firm is `Collection<Collection<String>>` and when trying to invoke it with a `List<List<String>>` I get the following error

```
/MyClass.java:10: error: incompatible types: List<List<String>> cannot be converted to Collection<Collection<String>>
        method(matrix);
```

This is an example of my code (not actually my code)

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<List<String>> matrix = List.of(
          List.of("q", "w", "e", "r", "t", "y"),
          List.of("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6")
        );
        method(matrix);
        
    }
    
    private static void method(Collection<Collection<String>> matrix){
        //method here
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Collection<? extends Collection<String>> matrix` would work.

Comment: You can add a `Set<String>` to a `Collection<Collection<String>>`; but you shouldn't add a `Set<String>` to a `List<List<String>>`. Hence, they aren't compatible types.